# Change ZOO cache update frequency

Tags: cache, zoo, zoo-cck

Is there a way to modify the interval that the zoo cache updates thumbnails? OR disable it entirely? I have been sorting through the code and haven't found anyway yet. 
 The problem I am running into is that it regenerates the thumbnails frequently which gives the image a new name in the zoo cache.  Because of that, it makes a CDN pretty useless in terms of speeding the site up and adds extra load to the server.

**NOTES:** I am fine with hacking it.  It is not an option to switch to different CCK.

Comment: What component are you use? Image or Image Pro from Zoolandres?